# the number of pthread_mutex in running system

Tags: linux, kernel

I have a strange question. I have to calculate the number of
pthread_mutex in running system, for example, debian, ubuntu,system in
microcontroller  and etc. I have to do it without LD_PRELOAD,
interrupting, overloading of functions and etc. I have to calculate it
in random time.
Do somebody have idea how I can do it? Can you see me way?

Answer (score 0):

for the count the threads:

`ps -eLf` will give you a list of all the threads and processes currently running on the system.

However you ask for a list of all threads that HAVE executed on the system, presumably since some arbitrary point in the past - are you sure that is what you mean? You could run ps as a cron job and poll the system every X minutes, but you would miss threads that were born and died between jobs. You would also have a huge amount of data to deal with.

For count the mutex it's impossible

Comment: I just have to write program, execute it, and it has to show how many ptread_mutex in system.